# Stop bootstrap 3 from creating padding on ends of navbar buttons

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm working on building a collapsible nav bar for my website (in bootstrap 3). The navbar its self works great, but I noticed that bootstrap creates a "block" sort of thing out of each li tag. I realize that it needs to do this so when the nav collapses, there are full width blocks of each link that the user can click on. My issue is that since these "blocks" are equal on both sides, I cannot line up my menu text perfectly with the edges of the container. I've tried to remove the left padding from the Home button and the right padding from the Contact button, without any success. I mainly only need this for screens 768px and above, since the nav isn't collapsed for these sizes.

In a nut shell, I need the menu text to line up at the beginning and end of the container bellow it. Here is a bootply:

http://bootply.com/112029

Any suggestions on how to solve this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you want to do this because if you hover over your nav links, you can see they align perfectly with the body container.But if you still want to do it, you can add a custom class to your nav's container, let's call it .custom-cont and then use this.

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
.custom-cont {
width: 84%;
}
```

[Bootply](http://bootply.com/112043)

Although it align your text with the body container but you can notice the effect on hover.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you. I removed the hover and click effects of the buttons, so the user will never really know that the button lines up with the container. The container and buttons are all one color. Thanks again!